# Python RegEx: How to remove all characters to the left of and including a given character

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to remove every character to the left of the first "[" bracket, as well as the bracket itself. All I want to remain are the host ID's. Can someone help me out and show me a way to do this in RegEx?

```
 warnings.warn(
resources: [
  b484e9aa2xxxe95a3225,
  9a854531xxx2a4f84394c,
  e127d90xxxe0825d7c949,
  3252014xxxd8568b4Gsd3,
```

Comment: Maybe `text.split("[")[-1]` is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that matches everything up to the first `[` character, and replace it with an empty string.

```
text = re.sub(r'^.*?\[', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The `re.DOTALL` flag makes `.*` match across newlines. And the `?` after `.*` makes it non-greedy, so it stops at the first `[` rather than the last one.